# A function vanishing at infinity which is not $L_1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

I need an example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow  \mathbb {R}$ vanishing at infinity, i.e. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f (x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f (x)=0$$  but $f$ is not $L_1$.

Comment: Well, e.g. $f(x)=1/(1+|x|)$.

Comment: Thanks, and the integration goes to $\infty$ cause $\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow \infty$ as  $n\rightarrow \infty$. Am I correct?

Comment: It's because $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n+1} \color{red}{=} \infty$, yes.

Comment: oh..sorry it's equal to ...yeah..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat cruder example, respect to the one given by saz in the comments, is the following one
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & |x|<1\\
|x|^{-1} & |x|\ge 1
\end{cases}.
$$
The function $f(x)$ vanishes at the infinity but, for any any $R>1$,
$$
I(R)=\int\limits_{[-R,R]}\!f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= 2\log(R)\underset{R\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty\iff f\notin L^1(\mathbf{R})
$$
**A second example**: as noted by the OP, the function $f(x)$ in the above example is not continuous. However, by slightly correcting it we can define $g(x)$ as
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
|x| & |x|<1\\
|x|^{-1} & |x|\ge 1
\end{cases}.
$$
The function $g$ is continuous ($\in C^0(\mathbf{R}$)) and again, for every $R>1$, we have
$$
I^\prime(R)=\int\limits_{[-R,R]}\!g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= 1+2\log(R)\underset{R\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty\iff g\notin L^1(\mathbf{R}).
$$
**A third example**. Finally, defining $h(x)$ as
$$
h(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}(3-x^2) & |x|<1\\
|x|^{-1} & |x|\ge 1
\end{cases}.
$$
we have $h\in C^1(\mathbf{R})$ and for every $R>1$
$$
I^{\prime\prime}(R)=\int\limits_{[-R,R]}\!h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= \frac{8}{3}+2\log(R)\underset{R\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty\iff h\notin L^1(\mathbf{R}).
$$

Comment: But it's not continuous

Comment: Yes, it si not continuous because I used a discontinuous *cut-off* around the origin of the real line. Of course you can mollify it and get a function as smooth as you need. I’ll correct the answer later if you are interested in seeing how to do.

Comment: Yeah.....I think we can make it smooth using "bump functions" .

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniele

Comment: @PSG. I added two further examples, with $C^0$ and $C^1$ functions respectively: I did not followed the route I described in my previous comment since the new examples given are simpler and easier to understand than the ones producible by using a cutoff/bump function.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks again Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous, although informal example, is to create a function as follows:

In the interval $[-1,1]$ behaves like this $f(x)=100-|x|$, so the integral over the interval $[-1,1]$ evaluates to 100. Now, as $x$ grows in value towards $\infty$ or $-\infty$, define additional triangles at a constant distance between one another, so that the peak of each triangle is half the height of the previous peak, and the base is twice the size of the previous base.

This way, although $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$, the integral itself does not evaluate to a finite value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a smooth function with that property:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\ln(1+\cosh x)}$$